# Displaying json data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When my program gets a JSON response like this:

```
[
    {
      "index": 1,
      "name": "Samantha",
      "rarity": "Scarborough",
      "email": "maureen@sykes.mk"
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "name": "Amanda",
      "rarity": "Vick",
      "email": "jessica@livingston.mv"
    }
]
```

AngularJS is showing `ng-repeat` dupes error. I also tried using: track by `$index`.

---

But if my JSON response is like this:

```
{"items": 
   [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "name": "Samantha",
      "rarity": "Scarborough",
      "email": "maureen@sykes.mk"
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "name": "Amanda",
      "rarity": "Vick",
      "email": "jessica@livingston.mv"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can easily display the JSON using `ng-repeat = "name in variable.items"`

Why does AngularJS behave like this?

Comment: can you show the complete code ??

Comment: There might be some other problem because I give a try to above JSON with success. Can you please show your complete code ?

Comment: working fine without track by : https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/13dhcmm9/1/